# Are questions asking for lists of retreat centers/temples on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, off-topic

This is centered around [Meditation Retreat in India](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/meditation-retreat-in-india) and [Buddhist Centres in Paris?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2349/buddhist-centres-in-paris).

My personal view is that we, as a site, can't really afford to be an up-to-date list of Buddhist Centers with reviews and that such questions are not really an excellent fit for a Q&A format.

Answer (score 3):

> My personal view is that we, as a site, can't really afford to be an up-to-date list of Buddhist Centers with reviews and that such questions are not really an excellent fit for a Q&A format.

I would agree.

However, this community might find some success with questions about *how* to find or choose a retreat center. You wouldn't curate a list, but perhaps a set of guidelines for how to go about finding and picking an establishment that's the right fit for you.

My $0.02 - this is up to you as a community.

Comment: For the record, this is the strategy we've used with some success on MA.SE. "What are centers in my area that teach X" is off topic, but "How can I choose a martial art based on these criteria?" is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: What is you refere by MA.SE?

Comment: @SumindaSirinathSalpitikorala Martial Arts Stack Exchange. Hrafn is a moderator over there too.

Answer (score 2):

I would close these of as off topic due to been too localised. Requests for specific resources limited to a specific geographic area are of of interest to a minority and I think just clutter the site. If we allow it, where do we draw the line? Meditation classes in the UK, or West Yorkshire, or Leeds, or a 1 mile radius from my house.

I would close the Indian and Paris centres questions and close off any future ones as too localised.

Answer (score -1):

Certain people may be looking for certain centres with certain criteria, certain traditions. Best is we keep this on topic so some one knowing the linage / tradition can help.